# How do I use a properties file in Java?

Tags: java

In the web application, which I am going to build, I need some SQL queries, which I can store in a properties file, and get them into my Java code, and then execute.

I have found many suggestions on the internet, but nothing helped me. Some of them are

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/file.properties");
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/file.properties");
```

I have kept the properties file in resources, and in the same directory in which my Java file is present. Nothing worked. I am using Eclipse and Struts2.

Comment: Where do you want to use the values from the properties file? in your action class? If so, there is a struts way of doing it.

Comment: I need to read the sql query in Dao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your properties files goes to `WEB-INF\classes`, where your `struts.xml` is. This folder is on the classpath. Then

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.properties");
```

should work as expected. Or of course, if you create a `resources` folder in `classes`, the aforementioned code should work too.

If by `resources` folder you mean `src/main/resources`, then it is managed by Maven, and it is copied directly to `WEB-INF/classes`. So you do not need to specify the `resorces` folder in the method.

Comment: I kept it in the same place(resources) where struts.xml file is present. Still I am getting "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: I am just using struts2 and tiles.

Comment: My project is working fine when I placed SQL queries in the java directly. Now I want to keep them in separate file and use in java.

Comment: Could you add a print screen about your project layout to the question? Also make sure that the properties file is actually in the WAR file!